CloudFormation API with Swagger gives "Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
I tried to add an options endpoint to my Api to fix the CORS issue. However, the following CloudFormation code gives a very strange error message:
LogUserActivityApi:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
DependsOn: LogUserActivityFunction
Properties:
  Name: !Join [ "", [ "log-user-activity-", !Ref environment ]]
  Description: General api to log user activity
  StageName: !Join [ "", [ !Ref environment, "stage"]]
  Auth:
    DefaultAuthorizer: MyCognitoAuthorizer
    Authorizers:
      MyCognitoAuthorizer:
        UserPoolArn: !Ref CognitoUserPoolArn
  DefinitionBody:
    swagger: 2.0
    info:
      version: "1.0"
      title: "log-user-activity"
    basePath: !Join [ "", [ "/", !Ref environment, "stage" ]]
    schemes:
    - "https"
    paths:
      /:
        get:
          responses: {}
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
            uri:
              # You need to build up the ARN with this pattern - you can't just use a !Ref or !GetAtt.
              Fn::Sub: arn:${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LogUserActivityFunction.Arn}/invocations
            passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
            httpMethod: "POST"
            type: "aws_proxy"
      /log-user-activity:
        post:
          consumes:
            - application/json
          produces:
            - application/json
          responses: {}
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
            uri:
              # You need to build up the ARN with this pattern - you can't just use a !Ref or !GetAtt AFAIK.
              Fn::Sub: arn:${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LogUserActivityFunction.Arn}/invocations
            passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
            httpMethod: "POST"
            type: "aws_proxy"
        options:
          consumes:
            - application/json
          produces:
            - application/json
          responses:
            '200':
              description: Default response
              headers:
                Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
                  schema:
                    type: string
                Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
                  schema:
                    type: string
                Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                  schema:
                    type: string
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
            type: mock
            requestTemplates:
              application/json: |
                {"statusCode" : 200}
            responses:
              default:
                statusCode: '200'
                responseParameters:
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,PATCH'"
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"

I get the error:
Resource handler returned message: "Errors found during import: Unable to put integration response on 'OPTIONS' for resource at path '/log-user-activity': Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers] 

Can you spot any mistakes or is there an easier way to enable CORS for my Api in CloudFormation?
I already tried using lower case for the header names and just passing "'*'" or even trying to skip some in which case it doesn't solve the CORS issue.

Looks like you are using the OpenAPI 3 version of defining options and then also specifying swagger 2.  I would switch to openapi: "3.0.1" and delete swagger: 2.0 or switch to the 2 method of adding options.  You can see the docs here on how to do options with the 2.x version.
